# Gridlayout - how to add nothing to it?

Tags: java, function, layout, methods

So I have a gridlayout, and when I go through a loop in another class I want to either add a button there or not. How would I go through and add nothing if I dont want it to be there?

It is Nqueens, so I have to make a board specific to the size the user wants and then I have to show how it is possible by placing the buttons on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make the `add` statement conditional:

```
gbc.gridwidth = blah;
...
if (condition)
    container.add(component);
```

Comment: right but that wouldn't be at the right location would it? because that would just add them right next to eachother